# how assign new row value in update trigger to a variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to assign new row value of update trigger to a variable.I am doing this right now but getting in debug trigger.

```
SET @v_avgvafeedback:=NEW.rating;
SET @v_avgtycafeedback:=NEW.tycarating;
SET @v_avgssfeedback:=NEW.ssrating;

SET @v_avgvafeedback:=((@v_avgvafeedback+@v_oldvafeedback)/2);
SET @v_avgtycafeedback:=((@v_avgtycafeedback+@v_oldtycafeedback)/2);
SET @v_avgssfeedback:=((@v_avgssfeedback+@v_oldssfeedback)/2);

INSERT INTO debug_trigger(name,value,line)
VALUES('v_avgvafeedback',v_avgvafeedback,68),
('v_avgtycafeedback',v_avgtycafeedback,69),
('v_avgssfeedback',v_avgssfeedback,70);
```

Answer (score 0):

When i am understanding you correctly, the data inserted into your table  debug_trigger doesn't work.

that is because you didn't add the correct data

It must be

```
INSERT INTO debug_trigger(name,value,line)
VALUES('v_avgvafeedback',@v_avgvafeedback,68),
('v_avgtycafeedback',@v_avgtycafeedback,69),
('v_avgssfeedback',@v_avgssfeedback,70);
```

You must add the user defined variable.